# PerformSegueWithIdentifier if parameter values are correct for http POST request

Tags: swift, authentication, http-post, nsurlsession

When the parameter (params) values are incorrect, it still login to another view. In the console, both response body and response header return values when printed. Where have I gone wrong?

```
func login() {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://someurl/verify/")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let params =
        [
          "username":username.text!,
          "password":password.text!,
          "deviceid":"r49rvnjff",
          "method":"method",
          "payload":"payload"
        ]
            as Dictionary<String,String>

    print(params)

    do {
       request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error == nil {}

        let json: NSDictionary?
        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
        }
        catch let dataError {
            print(dataError)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            return
        }

        if let parseJSON = json {

            let authenticated = parseJSON["authenticated"] as? String
            print("authenticated:\(authenticated)")
            if authenticated  != "False" {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What does your invalid response look like? might it be that its returning "false" and not "False" (which is what you are checking for), in any case I would recommend verifying your response from the server so that you can have the *authenticated* parameter be a boolean, so you can unwrap your optional as so:

```
if let authenticated = json["authenticated"] as? Bool {
    if (authenticated) 
    { 
       // ...
    }
}
```

Also, I noticed that your else block will never be hit because your **json** property is unwrapped. Your serialization is successful so **json** is not nil, hence the **if let parseJSON = json** will always work.

I would suggest the following approach:

```
if let authenticated = json["authenticated"] as? Bool
{
    if (authenticated)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: self)
        }
     }
     else 
     {
         let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
         print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
     }
 }
```

Good luck!